# H81 Pro BTC R2.0 + 6x ASUS ROG Strix GeForce® GTX 1070

Tags: ether

I'm interesting to buy H81 Pro BTC R2.0 and 6x ASUS ROG Strix GeForce® GTX 1070
Does it work, how much mh/s can I get normally with 1x ASUS ROG Strix GeForce® GTX 1070?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One stock 1070 will give about 27MH/s at about 135W. 
If they are overclocked, you may see up to around 30MH/s.
6x 1070 at stock speed would be 27*6=162MH/s